# How to find the number of squares between a range of numbers that are also divisible by $ 12 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know to find all numbers divisible by $ 12 $ between a range of numbers is something like:

$$ \frac{x}{12} - \frac{y}{12} + 1, \quad \text{where}\ x>y .$$
And to find the number of squares would be:

$$\left \lfloor{\sqrt{y}} \right\rfloor- \left \lceil {\sqrt{x}} \right \rceil + 1$$

Is there some way to calculate the number of numbers that has both qualities?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you provide some context? See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 0):

To be a square divisible by $12$ a number needs to be divisible by $36$ because you need an even number of factors of $3$.  The square root then needs to be divisible by $6$.  So find the number of numbers divisible by $6$ between $\lceil \sqrt x \rceil$ and $\lfloor \sqrt y\rfloor$ inclusive